# Java Servlet Async Support

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Recently i have started working on Java Servlet Async functionality. I have written sample code shown below to check aysnc Functionality. I am running it on single core processor. I am submitting 100 requests (image requests) from jsp. I have added "Request Submmited:::" SOP in code. It is displaying SOP for first 0 to 6 requests then after some time it is displaying SOP for 6 to 11.... why it is not displaying SOP for all 100 requests.

```
package com.test;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.AsyncContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/Test"}, asyncSupported = true)
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Test() {
    super();
}

int counter = 0;
@Override
protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
    System.out.println("Request Submmited:::" + counter++);
    final AsyncContext ctx = request.startAsync();
    ctx.start(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String count = request.getParameter("test");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(
                        "D:/TESTImages/8_0_0_NUCLEI" + count + ".jpg");
                byte[] data = new byte[fin.available()];
                fin.read(data);
                response.getWriter().print(new String(data));
                response.flushBuffer();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ctx.complete();
        }
    });
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the default thread pool size is **5**, for the pool that procesess async requests in your servlet container. Try providing init params as below:

```
@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/Test"}, asyncSupported = true, 
initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "threadpoolsize", value = "100") })
```